# Issues to list classes and subclasses with Jena

Tags: java, api, jena

I'm not getting to list all subclasses of a class. I list the classes, my algorithm checks if each class has a subclass. If true, was to list all subclasses. But this doesn´t happen, it seems to ignore the condition "if (essaClasse.hasSubClass). Can anyone help me? Bellow the code part.

Thanks!

Debora 
(Rio de Janeiro - Brasil)

The full code:

```
package testejena;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class testeProp {

    static final String inputFileName = "OBRecortada3.owl";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            //create the reasoning model using the base
            OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

            // use the FileManager to find the input file
            InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
            if (in == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
            }

            inf.read(in, "");

            String URI = "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/OntologyBase.owl#";

            ExtendedIterator classes = inf.listClasses();
            while (classes.hasNext()) {
                OntClass essaClasse = (OntClass) classes.next();

                String vClasse = essaClasse.getLocalName().toString();

                if (essaClasse.hasSubClass()) {
                    System.out.println("Classe: " + vClasse);
                    OntClass cla = inf.getOntClass(URI + vClasse);
                    for (Iterator i = cla.listSubClasses(); i.hasNext();) {
                        OntClass c = (OntClass) i.next();
                        System.out.print("   " + c.getLocalName() + " " + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: For completeness, can you please either include the file `OBRecortada3.owl`, or post a link to where it can be found on-line.

Comment: I posted the full code above. Thanks.

Comment: The contents of the ontology are still not shown. Your code looks OK to me - so I suspect it's an issue with your data. However, unless we can look at the data, it's not possible to say for sure, or, indeed, to say what the problem is and how you can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your data or complete code (including the bit where you set up the OntModel object), so it's hard to give definitive advice. The `hasSubClass` method is tested in the Jena unit tests, so it's unlikely (though not impossible) that it contains a bug. I would suggest checking that:

- you are correctly loading the data into the `Model` before you run the above code, using a debugger or log statements to show, for example, the number of triples loaded
- that ontology you are loading does in fact contain sub-class statements, including checking the prefix declaration used to define `rdfs` in any `rdfs:subClassOf` triples (it must be *exactly* `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#`)

Comment: Hi Ian!
My code and ontology are small, so I able to check the algoritm result with ontology. Bellow (or above) the complete code. I don't know if I can to post here the ontology that I'm using, so I will post the algoritm results. I'm little time this forum, so you forgive me "by gaffes". Thank so much.

Comment: I could not post the pictures the result of the code, but I'm new to the forum. Sorry.

Comment: I think that problem is in "classe.hasSubClass", but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: You could post the full details of your code to gist or pastebin and put the link in a comment here. Or, you could edit your question to include your source code: make sure you indent all code by four extra spaces, so that it is recognized as source code.

Comment: I tested it with other ontologies and got the same problem, what I realized is that I will not list all classes and subclasses. If I delete the "if (essaClasse.hasSubClass ())" gives the same result, ie, this condition is not valid. Another question, every class is a subclass of Thing, right?

Answer (score 1):

your algorithm wasn't working because you didn't specify an `OntModelSpec` in your `OntModel`. Specifying an `OntModelSpec` this code works perfectly!

```
OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
```